# C++ Vector like class in C#

Tags: c#, c++, list, vector

What is the analogous class of C++ `std::vector` in C#?

I want a class where it keeps an internal array inside and supports insertion at the back in `O(1)` time.

Comment: There is no exact analogous of `std::vector` in C#.

Comment: Why is an array implementation important?  The more important aspect seems to be the constant append time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a list with some `C++` / `C#` containers that are *roughly* equivalent (not exact replacements) to each other:

- [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) -> [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) -> [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) -> [`SortedDictionary<Tkey, Tvalue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) -> [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) -> [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) -> [`SortedDictionary<Tkey, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (`int` keeping count of the number of `Tkey`s)
- [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) -> [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: std::set - HashSet<T> ?

Comment: But the OP wants O(1) insertion time, which doesn't exist in vector or List.

Comment: surely vector and list are O(1) insert, doesnt say anything about sorting

Comment: OP only asks for O(1) insertion *at the back*

Comment: List<T> have O(1) in add at the back if the size less than capacity. It s very important.

Comment: Using `List.Add()` can become O(n) operation if [capacity change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) is needed. `LinkedList`, however, guarantees O(1) [back insertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132177.aspx).

Comment: List.Add is O(1) amortized, that might count too - actually it *probably* does, because OP explicitly asks for an array-backed datastructure.

Comment: @WeylandYutani: neither `List<T>` nor `vector` are O(1) for all insertions (only those that happen at `index == count`, and if a resize occurs this wouldn't be the case either).

Comment: ah i was confusing insert in middle with replace

Comment: std::set is equivalent to SortedSet; std::unordered_set is HashSet. Same for std::map.

Comment: Good concise answer

Answer (score -3):

- std::list -> LinkedList ?
- std::vector -> List ?

std::list is backed by array, each deletion would incur memory copy, same behavior as C# List.
while C# LinkedList is backed by node list, same as std::vector.

so I believe below is correct.

- std::list -> List
- std::vector -> LinkedList

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: std::vector is not backed by a linked list, it specifically stores data contiguously in memory (like an array). Source: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/ - second paragraph.